# Common among the common things

Tags: wordplay

What is common among the following and identify one such word (which can belong to the series):

Are, Below, Pines, Keen,  Gel, Kins, Vine

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are

> Body Anagrams:
>  Ear, Elbow, Spine, Knee, Leg, Skin, Vein
>  So next maybe ram, inch…

Comment: Yes, @Jan Ivan, you got it correct ! It should be body parts, not the body itself !! Next one could be lain !